# Material Dialog vs. Bootstrap Modal: Angular 5, 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm currently developing an application in Angular 5 and soon upgrading to Angular 6. I have certain requirements for the project that I'm working on that requires some static as well as dynamic content in a modal. Doing some research, I found out 2 options:

1. Angular Material Dialog
   https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview
2. Bootstrap Modal

I am currently using some components from the Angular material, but not using Dialog for now. So I'm confused whether to go with Material Dialog since Material is very popular in the Angular world or use Bootstrap Modal as I have used Bootstrap in the past and I know it works great.
I created a test dialog from Material to see how it is working and as far as I can tell, Material Dialogs are great for modals that vertically fit in the screen. I mean we can have a way to make the center of the Material Dialog scrollable but we can't really make the whole dialog really long with a lot of static content as Material Dialogs are not scrollable. I think Bootstrap Modals does allow you to have a really long modal and you can easily scroll the entire modal.

But please give me some suggestion what will actually be good on the architecture side.

Comment: Don't you think it is primarily opinion based?

Comment: Yes it may be. Is this not the right portal for such questions? :)

Comment: Not it's not. Probably a good Google Search on Angular Material VS Bootstrap should yield you proper results. PS: I didn't downvote you BTW. Just saying.

Comment: From a design point of view, you shouldn't mix Material and plain Bootstrap - they are different experiences. However, I believe a material design for bootstrap package is available. Either way, I think it's a design mistake to use un-material design elements in a material design application, and to a lesser extent to use material-design design elements in a non material design application. Decide what you want your application to be design wise and choose components accordingly.